# How to redirect stdin to file in bash

Tags: bash

Consider this very simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > /tmp/file
```

It redirects whatever you pipe into it to a file. e.g.

```
echo "hello" | script.sh
```

and "hello" will be in the file /tmp/file. This works... but it seems like there should be a native bash way of doing this without using "cat". But I can't figure it out.

NOTE:

1. It *must* be in a script. I want the script to operate on the file contents afterwards.
2. It *must* be in a file, the steps afterward in my case involve a tool that only reads from a file.
3. I *already* have a pretty good way of doing this - its just that it seems like a hack. Is there a *native* way? Like "/tmp/file < 0 " or "0> /tmp/file". I thought bash would have a native syntax to do this...

Comment: `echo "hello" > file`

Comment: I provided you an answer below, but I don't personally feel that using `cat` is a hack. You'd use `sed` or `awk` if needed? So why not `cat`?

Comment: Agree that using cat in this case is not a "hack" if there is no native way to do it. Surprised that it seems that there isn't one.

Comment: @RafaelBaptista, keep in mind that bash uses NUL-delimited C strings. A file can contain NUL literals, but a shell variable can't. This means that any approach that involves copying content into a shell variable (or some other string internally represented by the shell) will necessarily be lossy, unless implemented in a manner that goes to explicit lengths to be correct in this scenario (ie. using `IFS= read -r -d '' string`, and checking both exit status and whether the variable is populated to determine whether to print content with a trailing NUL, to print content bare, or to exit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is a builtin that reads from stdin until EOF, but you can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec > /tmp/file
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```

Comment: This will work, and its native in the sense that it doesn't use anything but bash builtins. More awkward than the cat method, since you are reading line by line.

Comment: At the very least, you should use `IFS= read -r a` and `printf '%s\n' "$a"` to ensure you don't lose any leading or trailing whitespace from a line, or interpret any backslashes as escape sequences.

Comment: `IFS="\n"` is putting two characters, the backslash, and `n`, into `IFS`. Perhaps you want `IFS=$'\n'`.

Comment: And `echo $a` is going to change a line containing `*` into a list of files.

Comment: ...since this has been accepted answer, and there have been no responses to correctness-related concerns for a rather extended period, I'm stepping over the line a bit here and editing it as necessary to ensure that outputs are identical to inputs (to the extent possible; doesn't handle input with missing trailing newlines or NULs).

Answer (score 54):

You could simply do

```
cp /dev/stdin  myfile.txt
```

Terminate your input with Ctrl+D  or Ctrl+Z and, viola! You have your file created with text from the stdin.

Comment: `cp` is not a built-in in bash.

Comment: ...and that's good because it allows you to use the command with other shells.

Comment: Seems /dev/stdin will require root access

Comment: This is awesome! It worked for me on a kubernates pod where vim is not installed.

Comment: worked well for shoving text into a logfile over Python's `paramiko` library

Answer (score 17):

```
echo "$(</dev/stdin)" > /tmp/file
```

terminate your input with <kbd>ENTER</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>

Comment: This will remove any NULs present in the stream. It also will unconditionally add a trailing newline, whether or not one existed in the input.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The command substitution will load all into memory.  If there is a lot of data in stdin there might be a problem. Better `cat - > /tmp/file`

Comment: @Roland, ah. Yup, your comment is quite correct.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it using pure BASH:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS= read -t 0.01 -r -d '' indata

[[ -n $indata ]] && printf "%s" "$indata" >/tmp/file
```

`IFS=` and `-d ''` causes all of stdin data to be read into a variable `indata`.

**Reason of using `-t 0.01`:** When this script is called with no input pipe then `read` will timeout after negligible `0.01` seconds delay. If there is any data available in input it will be read in `indata` variable and it will be redirected to `>/tmp/file`.

Comment: If someone runs `slow-java-program | yourscript`, is it appropriate to ignore any input not promptly delivered (because the input source is far slower to initialize)?

Answer (score 3):

Another option: `dd of=/tmp/myfile/txt`

***Note:*** *This is **not** a built-in, however, it might help other people looking for a simple solution.*

Comment: This is a pretty simple way to achieve the basic purpose of piping a *STDIN* steam into a file. Your answer helps people running into this issue. However, it does not fit the SO's question since `dd` is a user space utility and not a shell built-in. You should place some notice in your answer when providing alternatives for other visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just

```
GENERATE INPUT | (
    # do whatever you like to the input here
)
```

But sometimes, especially when you want to complete the input first, then operate on the modified output, you should still use temporary files:

```
TMPFILE="/tmp/fileA-$$"
GENERATE INPUT | (
    # modify input
) > "$TMPFILE"
(
     # do something with the input from TMPFILE
) < "$TMPFILE"
rm "$TMPFILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the program to end after reaching EOF, this might be helpful.

```
#!/bin/bash
exec < <(tail -F /tmp/a)
cat -
```